# Finding the basis vector of null space, how?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-equations, homogeneous-equation

Context from [this video](https://youtu.be/_CpshMm-5p0?t=353) and the lecturer did not proceed to solve for the basis vectors of this null space.:
[image]

I need to find the basis vector of the null space and I get that we need to first find the null space followed by finding the basis. I follow through until I'm instructed to apply the gaussian algorithm. But all I get is the following after gausian elimination:
$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\0&1\\0&0\\0&0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix}=x_1\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix} + x_2\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$.

Does that mean the basis vectors are... $\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2\end{pmatrix}$...?.. how do I find the values?....

Comment: $x_1$ and $x_2$ are paramters for the directions. The two vectors they multiply? Take that as your basis.

Comment: Thanks, what are the two vectors they multiply...? Do you mean $\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$ & $\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$? Those are my basis?

Comment: Exactly. That is a basis of the null space.

Comment: @SeanRoberson No, this is not right. Look at the question in the screenshot.

Comment: Wait so $\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$ & $\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$ are **not** the basis vectors in that null space?

Answer (score 2):

The basis vectors are:
$$\begin{pmatrix}-2 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix} \quad \text{ and } \quad \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ -3 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}.$$
Why? Recall that bases are defined by two properties: linear independence and spanning.

As Gauss-Jordan elimination of whatever homogenous system you started with showed, a general vector in $\operatorname{Null} A$ took the form
$$\vec{x} = s\begin{pmatrix}-2 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix} + t\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ -3 \\ 1\end{pmatrix},$$
where $s$ and $t$ are arbitrary scalars. That is, every element of $\operatorname{Null} A$ is a linear combination of the above vectors, which means the above vectors span $\operatorname{Null} A$.

To verify linear independence, we simply need to prove that
$$s\begin{pmatrix}-2 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix} + t\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ -3 \\ 1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix} \implies s = t = 0.$$
Equating the second coordinates, $1s + 0t = 0 \implies s = 0$. Equating the fourth coordinates, $0s + 1t = 0 \implies t = 0$ (that's why the second and fourth rows are highlighted). So, the only possible solution is $s = t = 0$, and the vectors are linearly independent. This completes the proof that they form a basis for $\operatorname{Null} A$.

Comment: I see, so the basis vectors are:  the $\vec{x}$ that would give the null space without the scalar infront? In that case why would the lecturer say at this point: "if you want to figure out the basis for the nullspace... just appy the gaussian algorithm and the vectors are the baiss that you get, those are going to be your answers" (Reference: https://youtu.be/_CpshMm-5p0?t=343). Did he make a mistake?

Comment: Additional question: Also, in that case, why would he mention we need to apply the gaussian algorithm if those are the basis vectors of nullspace already...?

Comment: He's saying that the procedure done so far works in general. He *already* applied  Gaussian elimination to get to the matrix in reduced row echelon form, from which he extracted free parameters, which allowed him to find these basis vectors. All he's saying is that these same steps will work with other matrices as well.